# How to rollback a transaction in Date Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to use the Data Entity Framework to create my Data Access Layer.  In the work I have done up to now I have used ADO.Net.  I am trying to get my head around how transactions work in EF. I ave read loads but its all confussed me even more than I was before!!  I would usually do somethink like (simplified for example):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connString))
{
    using (SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_CreateNewInvoice", conn))
            {
                cmd.Transaction = trans;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvoiceName", Invoice.invoicename));
                 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvoiceAddess", Invoice.invoiceaddress));
                 _invoiceid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
            foreach (InvoiceLine inLine in Invoice.Lines)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertInvoiceLines", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Transaction = trans;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvNo", _invoiceid));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvLineQty", inLine.lineqty));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvLineGrossPrice", inLine.linegrossprice));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlError)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to do the same in EF:

```
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                var DbContext = new CCTStoreEntities();

                CCTInvoice invHead = new CCTInvoice();
                invHead.Name = Invoice.invoicename;
                invHead.Address = Invoice.invoiceaddress;

                DbContext.CCTInvoices.Add(invHead);
                DbContext.SaveChanges(false);
                _iid = invHead.InvoiceId;

                foreach (InvoiceLine inLine in Invoice.Lines)
                {
                    CCTInvoiceLine invLine = new CCTInvoiceLine();
                    invLine.InvoiceNo = _iid;
                    invLine.Quantity = inLine.lineqty;
                    invLine.GrossPrice = inLine.linegrossprice;
                    DbContext.CCTInvoiceLines.Add(invHead);
                    DbContext.SaveChanges(false);
                }

                DbContext.SaveChanges();
                scope.Complete();

            }
            catch
            {
                //Something went wrong
                //Rollback!
            }
        }
```

From what I read `SaveChanges(false)` means the changes being made will continue to be tracked. But how do I rollback the transaction if something goes wrong?

Comment: SaveChanges is Transactional by default and you should be setting all your lines before calling saveChanges. Is there any reason for not doing it?

Comment: @LuisFilipe No reason except my limited knowledge of how the entity framework works.  I really am in the beginners stage with it all.

Comment: I am a beginner in EF too. Make the changes you want in memory and at the end call SaveChanges();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything on your catch block.  Just by not calling `DbContext.SaveChanges` no changes will be sent to the database, and they will be lost once DbContext is disposed.

You do have a problem though.  DbContext must be wrapped on a `using` block as follows to be properly disposed.  BTW, I don't think `DbContext.SaveChanges(false);` is needed, your code should work with just the final `DbContext.SaveChanges();`. EF will take care of wiring up all your Foreign Keys, so you don't need to do that explicitly.

```
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        try
        {
            using (var DbContext = new CCTStoreEntities())
            {
                CCTInvoice invHead = new CCTInvoice();
                invHead.Name = Invoice.invoicename;
                invHead.Address = Invoice.invoiceaddress;

                DbContext.CCTInvoices.Add(invHead);
                DbContext.SaveChanges(false); // This is not needed
                _iid = invHead.InvoiceId;     // This is not needed

                foreach (InvoiceLine inLine in Invoice.Lines)
                {
                    CCTInvoiceLine invLine = new CCTInvoiceLine();
                    invLine.InvoiceNo = _iid; // This is not needed
                    invLine.Quantity = inLine.lineqty;
                    invLine.GrossPrice = inLine.linegrossprice;
                    DbContext.CCTInvoiceLines.Add(invHead);
                    DbContext.SaveChanges(false); // This is not needed
                }

                DbContext.SaveChanges();
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Something went wrong
            //Rollback!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The rollback mechanism in a `TransactionScope` is implicit.

Basically, if you don't call `Complete` before the `TransactionScope` gets disposed it will automatically rollback. See the **Rolling back a transaction** section in [Implementing an Implicit Transaction using Transaction Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So technically, you don't even need to use a `try...catch` here (unless you want to perform some other action like logging).

Comment: Ok thanks now this makes sense. I do want to log failures so will keep the try catch.  And what you are saying is that the rollback will happen automatically if I dont make the call to Complete, which it won't do if an exception is raised.